# Is it possible to use scalap from a scala script?

Tags: scala, reflection, case-class, scalap

I am using `scalap` to read out the field names of some case classes (as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224251/109942)). Both the case classes and the code that uses `scalap` to analyze them have been compiled and put into a jar file on the classpath.

Now I want to run a script that uses this code, so I followed [the instructions](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/scala.html) and came up with something like

```
::#!
@echo off
call scala -classpath *;./libs/* %0 %*
goto :eof
::!#
//Code relying on pre-compiled code that uses scalap
```

which does not work:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.None$ cannot be cast to scala.Option
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ByteCode$.caseParamNamesForPath(ByteCode.
>   scala:45)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProductCompletion.caseNames(ProductComple
>   tion.scala:22)

However, the code works just fine when I compile everything. I played around with additional `scala` options like `-savecompiled`, but this did not help. Is this a bug, or can't this work in principle? (If so, could someone explain why not? As I said, the case classes that shall be analyzed by `scalap` are compiled.)

*Note: I use Scala 2.9.1-1.*

**EDIT**

Here is what I am essentially trying to do (providing a simple way to create multiple instances of a case class):

```
//This is pre-compiled:
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProductCompletion
//...
trait MyFactoryTrait[T <: MyFactoryTrait[T] with Product] {
  this: T =>

  private[this] val copyMethod = this.getClass.getMethods.find(x => x.getName == "copy").get

  lazy val productCompletion = new ProductCompletion(this)

  /** The names of all specified fields. */
  lazy val fieldNames = productCompletion.caseNames //<- provokes the exception (see above)

  def createSeq(...):Seq[T] = {
    val x = fieldNames map { ... } // <- this method uses the fieldNames value
    //[...] invoke copyMethod to create instances
  }   
 // ...
}

//This is pre-compiled too: 
case class MyCaseClass(x: Int = 0, y: Int = 0) extends MyFactoryTrait[MyCaseClass]

//This should be interpreted (but crashes):
val seq = MyCaseClass().createSeq(...)
```

*Note: I moved on to Scala 2.9.2, the error stays the same (so probably not a bug).*

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more of your code?

Comment: @Edmondo1984: sure, see above.

Comment: It looks like I need more information. If I take off the parameters from createSeq and return Seq.empty[T] I cannot obtain a compiler crash...

Comment: If you return an empty sequence and don't rely on fieldNames (which is a _lazy_ val), this should indeed be no problem. What's causing the crash is `productCompletion.caseNames` (see comments in sample code). Thanks for trying; I'll clarify the sample code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is  a bug in the compiler:

- If you run the program inside an ide, for example Intellij IDEA the code is executed fine, however no fields names are found.
- If you run it from command line using scala, you obtain the error you mentioned.

There is no way type-safe could should ever compiler and throw a runtime  ClassCastException.

Please open a bug at https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa