# In scala, use reflection on a case class classtag to find the companion object's apply method

Tags: scala, reflection

This is related to the following question, but since it concerns a distinct and salient issue, I'm asking it as a follow up: [Support generic deserialization from a List[(String, Any)] in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920030/support-generic-deserialization-from-a-liststring-any-in-scala/23920667?noredirect=1#23920667)

How can I use reflection to find the methods of the companion object for a `ClassTag`? Specifically, I'm trying to call the `apply` method of a case class' companion object reflectively to construct an instance of a case class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020746/get-companion-object-instance-with-new-scala-reflection-api/11031443#11031443) help you?

Here is an example for `scalaVersion := "2.11.1"`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => u}

def companionMembers(clazzTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[_]): u.MemberScope = {
  val runtimeClass = clazzTag.runtimeClass
  val rootMirror = u.runtimeMirror(runtimeClass.getClassLoader)
  val classSymbol = rootMirror.classSymbol(runtimeClass)
  // get the companion here
  classSymbol.companion.typeSignature.members
}

case class MyClass(value: Int)

val applyMethods =
  companionMembers(scala.reflect.classTag[MyClass])
  .filter { m => m.isMethod && m.name.toString == "apply"}

println(applyMethods)
```

prints

```
Scope{
  case def apply(value: scala.Int): MyClass
}
```

Comment: Yes, something like this works ok. I ended up using `private val apply = ctag.runtimeClass.getDeclaredMethods.find(m => "apply".equals(m.getName)).get`.