# Merge two case classes in Scala, but with deeply nested types, without lens boilerplate

Tags: scala, lenses

Similar to [this case class question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288964/merge-two-case-class-of-same-type-except-some-fields) but with a twist:

I have a case class which has some deeply nested case classes as properties.  As a simple example,

```
case class Foo(fooPropA:Option[String], fooPropB:Option[Int])
case class Bar(barPropA:String, barPropB:Int)
case class FooBar(name:Option[String], foo:Foo, optionFoo: Option[Foo], bar:Option[Bar])
```

I'd like to merge two FooBar case classes together, taking the values which exist for an input and applying them to an existing instance, producing an updated version:

```
val fb1 = FooBar(Some("one"), Foo(Some("propA"), None), Some(Foo(Some("propA"), Some(3))), Some(Bar("propA", 4)))
val fb2 = FooBar(None, Foo(Some("updated"), Some(2)), Some(Foo(Some("baz"), None)), None)
val merged = fb1.merge(fb2)
//merged = FooBar(Some("one"), Foo(Some("updated"), Some(2)), Some(Foo(Some("baz"), Some(3))), Some(Bar("propA", 4)))
```

I know I can use a lens to compose the deeply nested property updates; however, I feel this will require a lot of boiler plate code: I need a lens for every property, and another composed lens in the parent class.  This seems like a lot to maintain, even if using the more succinct lens creation approach in [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

The tricky part is the optionFoo element: in this scenario, both elements exist with a Some(value).  However, I'd like to merge the inner-option properties, not just overwrite fb1 with fb2's new values.

I'm wondering if there is a good approach to merge these two values together in a way which requires minimal code.  My gut feeling tells me to try to use the `unapply` method on the case class to return a tuple, iterate over and combine the tuples into a new tuple, and then apply the tuple back to a case class.

Is there a more efficient way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 10):

One clean way to tackle this problem is to think of your merge operation as something like addition given the right set of monoid instances. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11439044/334519) for a solution to a very similar problem, but the solution is even easier now thanks to [the efforts](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib) of the [typelevel](http://typelevel.org/) team. First for the case classes:

```
case class Foo(fooPropA: Option[String], fooPropB: Option[Int])
case class Bar(barPropA: String, barPropB: Int)
case class FooBar(name: Option[String], foo: Foo, bar: Option[Bar])
```

Then some boilerplate (which won't be necessary in the upcoming 2.0 release of Shapeless):

```
import shapeless._

implicit def fooIso = Iso.hlist(Foo.apply _, Foo.unapply _)
implicit def barIso = Iso.hlist(Bar.apply _, Bar.unapply _)
implicit def fooBarIso = Iso.hlist(FooBar.apply _, FooBar.unapply _)
```

I'm going to cheat just a little for the sake of clarity and put the "second" monoid instance for `Option` into scope instead of using tags:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import shapeless.contrib.scalaz._

implicit def optionSecondMonoid[A] = new Monoid[Option[A]] {
  val zero = None
  def append(a: Option[A], b: => Option[A]) = b orElse a
}
```

And we're done:

```
scala> val fb1 = FooBar(Some("1"), Foo(Some("A"), None), Some(Bar("A", 4)))
fb1: FooBar = FooBar(Some(one),Foo(Some(propA),None),Some(Bar(propA,4)))

scala> val fb2 = FooBar(None, Foo(Some("updated"), Some(2)), None)
fb2: FooBar = FooBar(None,Foo(Some(updated),Some(2)),None)

scala> fb1 |+| fb2
res0: FooBar = FooBar(Some(1),Foo(Some(updated),Some(2)),Some(Bar(A,4)))
```

See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11439044/334519) for some additional discussion.

Comment: Travis, thanks for this solution.  It's a very interesting approach. One question though: how can we recurse to combine two Some(_) values which may have Option sub properties?  For instance, what if the foo property in FooBar was foo:Option[Foo], and I wanted to apply |+| to both fooPropA and fooPropB?

Comment: That's exactly the behavior of the default monoid instance for `Option`, which is overriden here by the second instance (which is what you want for the `Option[String]` and `Option[Int]` fields). You can mix and match the behaviors using [tags](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Tags.scala)—I could write up a quick example later if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks Travis, I'd really appreciate a sample.  I'm new to Scalaz and Shapeless- I think I know what I want to happen, but not sure how to implement.  The way I see it is that when the code gets to an element in the Hlist that it can convert to an Hlist, convert it, and apply the |+| to the inner hlist and convert back to a case class.  I'll update my question with this scenario as well.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a Shapeless 2.x answer for this now?

Comment: @kali Done (in a new answer).

Answer (score 5):

My previous answer used Shapeless 1.2.4, Scalaz, and shapeless-contrib, and Shapeless 1.2.4 and shapeless-contrib are pretty outdated at this point (over two years later), so here's an updated answer using Shapeless 2.2.5 and [cats](https://github.com/non/cats) 0.3.0. I'll assume a build configuration like this:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.2.5",
  "org.spire-math" %% "cats" % "0.3.0"
)
```

Shapeless now includes a `ProductTypeClass` type class that we can use here. Eventually Miles Sabin's [kittens](https://github.com/milessabin/kittens) project (or something similar) is likely to provide this kind of thing for cats's type classes (similar to the role that shapeless-contrib played for Scalaz), but for now just using `ProductTypeClass` isn't too bad:

```
import algebra.Monoid, cats.std.all._, shapeless._

object caseClassMonoids extends ProductTypeClassCompanion[Monoid] {
  object typeClass extends ProductTypeClass[Monoid] {
    def product[H, T <: HList](ch: Monoid[H], ct: Monoid[T]): Monoid[H :: T] =
      new Monoid[H :: T] {
        def empty: H :: T = ch.empty :: ct.empty
        def combine(x: H :: T, y: H :: T): H :: T =
         ch.combine(x.head, y.head) :: ct.combine(x.tail, y.tail)
      }

    val emptyProduct: Monoid[HNil] = new Monoid[HNil] {
      def empty: HNil = HNil
      def combine(x: HNil, y: HNil): HNil = HNil
    }

    def project[F, G](inst: => Monoid[G], to: F => G, from: G => F): Monoid[F] =
      new Monoid[F] {
        def empty: F = from(inst.empty)
        def combine(x: F, y: F): F = from(inst.combine(to(x), to(y)))
      }
  }
}
```

And then:

```
import cats.syntax.semigroup._
import caseClassMonoids._

case class Foo(fooPropA: Option[String], fooPropB: Option[Int])
case class Bar(barPropA: String, barPropB: Int)
case class FooBar(name: Option[String], foo: Foo, bar: Option[Bar])
```

And finally:

```
scala> val fb1 = FooBar(Some("1"), Foo(Some("A"), None), Some(Bar("A", 4)))
fb1: FooBar = FooBar(Some(1),Foo(Some(A),None),Some(Bar(A,4)))

scala> val fb2 = FooBar(None, Foo(Some("updated"), Some(2)), None)
fb2: FooBar = FooBar(None,Foo(Some(updated),Some(2)),None)

scala> fb1 |+| fb2
res0: FooBar = FooBar(Some(1),Foo(Some(Aupdated),Some(2)),Some(Bar(A,4)))
```

Note that this combines values inside of `Some`, which isn't exactly what the question asks for, but is mentioned by the OP in a comment on my other answer. If you want the replacing behavior you can define the appropriate `Monoid[Option[A]]` as in my other answer.

Comment: I gave this a try, but had no success. I have the impression that some kind of implicit is missing? I added a implicitly[Monoid[Foo]], but got the same errors as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517069/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-emptycoproduct-and-coproduct-methods-of-the-typeclass/25559471#25559471, but I wasn't able to adapt the solution from there to here.

Comment: Ok, just tried it again with scala 2.11 instead of scala 2.10 and then it works flawlessly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Davi, yes, sorry—on 2.10 you'd need the Macro Paradise compiler plugin to make the generic derivation work.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Kittens 1.0.0-M8](https://github.com/milessabin/kittens), we're now able to derive a `Semigroup` (I thought it was enough for this example, but `Monoid` is a simply import away) without boilerplate at all:

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.derived._, semigroup._, legacy._

case class Foo(fooPropA: Option[String], fooPropB: Option[Int])
case class Bar(barPropA: String, barPropB: Int)
case class FooBar(name: Option[String], foo: Foo, bar: Option[Bar])

val fb1 = FooBar(Some("1"), Foo(Some("A"), None), Some(Bar("A", 4)))

val fb2 = FooBar(None, Foo(Some("updated"), Some(2)), None)
println(fb1 |+| fb2)
```

Yields:

```
FooBar(Some(1),Foo(Some(Aupdated),Some(2)),Some(Bar(A,4)))
```