# What is the purpose of the emptyCoproduct and coproduct methods of the TypeClass trait in Shapeless

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless, type-level-computation

It is not fully clear to me what is the purpose of the `emptyCoProduct` and `coproduct` methods of the `TypeClass` trait in Shapeless.

When would one use the `TypeClass` trait instead of the `ProductTypeClass`?

What are some examples of ways those two methods would be implemented?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Suppose I've got a simple type class:

```
trait Weight[A] { def apply(a: A): Int }

object Weight {
  def apply[A](f: A => Int) = new Weight[A] { def apply(a: A) = f(a) }
}
```

And some instances:

```
implicit val stringWeight: Weight[String] = Weight(_.size)
implicit def intWeight: Weight[Int] = Weight(identity)
```

And a case class:

```
case class Foo(i: Int, s: String)
```

And an ADT:

```
sealed trait Root
case class Bar(i: Int) extends Root
case class Baz(s: String) extends Root
```

I can define a `ProductTypeClass` instance for my type class:

```
import shapeless._

implicit object WeightTypeClass extends ProductTypeClass[Weight] {
  def emptyProduct: Weight[HNil] = Weight(_ => 0)
  def product[H, T <: HList](hw: Weight[H], tw: Weight[T]): Weight[H :: T] =
    Weight { case (h :: t) => hw(h) + tw(t) }
  def project[F, G](w: => Weight[G], to: F => G, from: G => F): Weight[F] =
    Weight(f => w(to(f)))
}
```

And use it like this:

```
scala> object WeightHelper extends ProductTypeClassCompanion[Weight]
defined object WeightHelper

scala> import WeightHelper.auto._
import WeightHelper.auto._

scala> implicitly[Weight[Foo]]
res0: Weight[Foo] = Weight$$anon$1@4daf1b4d

scala> implicitly[Weight[Bar]]
res1: Weight[Bar] = Weight$$anon$1@1cb152bb

scala> implicitly[Weight[Baz]]
res2: Weight[Baz] = Weight$$anon$1@74930887
```

But!

```
scala> implicitly[Weight[Root]]
<console>:21: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Weight[Root]
              implicitly[Weight[Root]]
                        ^
```

This is a problem—it makes our automated type class instance derivation pretty much useless for ADTs. Fortunately we can use `TypeClass` instead:

```
implicit object WeightTypeClass extends TypeClass[Weight] {
  def emptyProduct: Weight[HNil] = Weight(_ => 0)
  def product[H, T <: HList](hw: Weight[H], tw: Weight[T]): Weight[H :: T] =
    Weight { case (h :: t) => hw(h) + tw(t) }
  def project[F, G](w: => Weight[G], to: F => G, from: G => F): Weight[F] =
    Weight(f => w(to(f)))
  def emptyCoproduct: Weight[CNil] = Weight(_ => 0)
  def coproduct[L, R <: Coproduct]
    (lw: => Weight[L], rw: => Weight[R]): Weight[L :+: R] = Weight {
      case Inl(h) => lw(h)
      case Inr(t) => rw(t)
    }
}
```

And then:

```
scala> object WeightHelper extends TypeClassCompanion[Weight]
defined object WeightHelper

scala> import WeightHelper.auto._
import WeightHelper.auto._

scala> implicitly[Weight[Root]]
res0: Weight[Root] = Weight$$anon$1@7bc44e19
```

All the other stuff above still works as well.

To sum up: Shapeless's `Coproduct` is a kind of abstraction over ADTs, and in general you should provide instances of `TypeClass` for your type classes instead of just `ProductTypeClass` whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

As of shapeless 2.3.2, the above example doesn't seem to compile. here's the updated one for future reference:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.test._

trait Weight[A] { def apply(a: A): Int }

object Weight {
  def apply[A](f: A => Int) = new Weight[A] { def apply(a: A) = f(a) }
}

case class Foo(i: Int, s: String)

sealed trait Root
case class Bar(i: Int) extends Root
case class Baz(s: String) extends Root

object Base {
  implicit val stringWeight: Weight[String] = Weight(_.size)
  implicit def intWeight: Weight[Int] = Weight(identity)
}

object ProductTC {
  object WeightHelper extends ProductTypeClassCompanion[Weight] {
    object typeClass extends ProductTypeClass[Weight] {
      def emptyProduct: Weight[HNil] = Weight(_ => 0)
      def product[H, T <: HList](hw: Weight[H], tw: Weight[T]): Weight[H :: T] =
        Weight { case (h :: t) => hw(h) + tw(t) }
      def project[F, G](w: => Weight[G], to: F => G,from: G => F): Weight[F] =
        Weight(f => w(to(f)))
    }
  }

  import Base._
  import WeightHelper._

  implicitly[Weight[Foo]]
  implicitly[Weight[Bar]]
  implicitly[Weight[Baz]]

  illTyped("implicitly[Weight[Root]]")
}

object TC {
  object WeightTypeClass extends TypeClassCompanion[Weight] {
    object typeClass extends TypeClass[Weight] {
      def emptyProduct: Weight[HNil] = Weight(_ => 0)
      def product[H, T <: HList](hw: Weight[H], tw: Weight[T]): Weight[H :: T] =
        Weight { case (h :: t) => hw(h) + tw(t) }
      def project[F, G](w: => Weight[G], to: F => G, from: G => F): Weight[F] =
        Weight(f => w(to(f)))
      def emptyCoproduct: Weight[CNil] = Weight(_ => 0)
      def coproduct[L, R <: Coproduct]
        (lw: => Weight[L], rw: => Weight[R]): Weight[L :+: R] = Weight {
        case Inl(h) => lw(h)
        case Inr(t) => rw(t)
      }
    }
  }

  import Base._
  import WeightTypeClass._

  implicitly[Weight[Root]]
}
```