# Getting the parameters of a case class through Reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, introspection, scala-2.10

As a follow up of 
[Matt R's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224251/reflection-on-a-scala-case-class), as Scala 2.10 has been out for quite an amount of time, what would be the best way to extract the fields and values of a case class. Taking a similar example:

```
case class Colour(red: Int, green: Int, blue: String) {
  val other: Int = 42
} 

val RBG = Colour(1,3,"isBlue")
```

I want to get a list (or array or any iterator for that matter) that would have the fields declared in the constructor as tuple values like these:

```
[(red, 1),(green, 3),(blue, "isBlue")]
```

I know the fact that there are a lot of examples on the net regarding the same issue but as I said, I wanted to know what should be the most ideal way to extract the required information

Comment: as case classes implement the Product trait you should be able to use the Product method: productIterator in conjunction with zipwithindex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Scala 2.10 reflection, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079113/scala-2-10-reflection-how-do-i-extract-the-field-values-from-a-case-class#16079804) is half of the things you need. It will give you the method symbols of the case class, so you know the order and names of arguments:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import ru._

def getCaseMethods[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T].members.collect {
  case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
}.toList

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

getCaseMethods[Person]  // -> List(value age, value name)
```

You can call `.name.toString` on these methods to get the corresponding method names.

The next step is to invoke these methods on a given instance. You need a runtime mirror for that

```
val rm = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
```

Then you can "mirror" an actual instance:

```
val p  = Person("foo", 33)
val pr = rm.reflect(p)
```

Then you can reflect on `pr` each method using `reflectMethod` and execute it via `apply`. Without going through each step separately, here is a solution altogether (see the `val value =` line for the mechanism of extracting a parameter's value):

```
def caseMap[T: TypeTag: reflect.ClassTag](instance: T): List[(String, Any)] = {
  val im = rm.reflect(instance)
  typeOf[T].members.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor =>
      val name  = m.name.toString
      val value = im.reflectMethod(m).apply()
      (name, value)
  } (collection.breakOut)
}

caseMap(p) // -> List(age -> 33, name -> foo)
```

Answer (score 5):

Every case object is a product, therefore you can use an iterator to get all its parameters' names and another iterator to get all its parameters' values:

```scala
case class Colour(red: Int, green: Int, blue: String) {
  val other: Int = 42
}

val rgb = Colour(1, 3, "isBlue")

val names = rgb.productElementNames.toList  // List(red, green, blue)
val values = rgb.productIterator.toList     // List(1, 3, isBlue)

names.zip(values).foreach(print)            // (red,1)(green,3)(blue,isBlue)
```

By **product** I mean both Cartesian product and an instance of [Product](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html). This requires Scala 2.13.0; although Product was available before, the iterator to get elements' names was only added in version 2.13.0.

Notice that no reflection is needed.

Comment: How to get types?